# how to set threshold for the battery charging?

Tags: power-management, battery

I'm on ubuntu 18.04 .. first Does this command make laptop using the charger not the battery ? and Does the battery using off ?

```
user@user:~$ sudo tlp start
TLP started in AC mode (auto).
```

how can i set the battery threshold while the battery every time i charged it exceeds 100 % 
while i used this command

```
user@user:~$ sudo tlp-stat -b
--- TLP 1.3.1 --------------------------------------------

+++ Battery Features: Charge Thresholds and Recalibrate
natacpi    = inactive (laptop not supported)
tpacpi-bat = inactive (laptop not supported)
tp-smapi   = inactive (laptop not supported)

+++ Battery Status: BAT0

/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/cycle_count                    =     13
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full_design             =  52500 
[mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_full                    =  51100 
[mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/energy_now                     =  51110 
[mWh]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/power_now                      =   4208 
[mW]
/sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/status                         = Charging

Charge                                                      =  100.0 
[%]
Capacity                                                    =   97.3 
[%]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use tlp to limit battery charging on your laptop:

`tp-smapi = interactive (laptop not supported)`

tlp only supports this feature on ThinkPads.

Comment: how can i solve it ?

Comment: Either buy a ThinkPad or try a different method.

Comment: laptop is new .. what are the different method you mean .. i'm stuck in this problem

Comment: This is but part of what the OP is asking... "How can i set the battery threshold ...?"